# Creating and Saving an Excel File

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, interop, webforms

I have the following code that creates a new Excel file in my C# code behind. When I attempt to save the file I would like the user to select the location of the save.

In Method #1, I can save the file my using the workbook SaveCopyAs without prompting the user for a location. This saves one file to the C:\Temp directory.

Method #2 will save the file in my Users\Documents folder, then prompt the user to select the location and save a second copy. How can I eliminate the first copy from saving in the Users\Documents folder?

```
Excel.Application oXL;
Excel._Workbook oWB;
Excel._Worksheet oSheet;
Excel.Range oRng;

try
{
    //Start Excel and get Application object.
    oXL = new Excel.Application();
    oXL.Visible = false;

    //Get a new workbook.
    oWB = (Excel._Workbook)(oXL.Workbooks.Add(Missing.Value));
    oSheet = (Excel._Worksheet)oWB.ActiveSheet;

    // *****
    oSheet.Cells[2, 6] = "Ship To:";
    oSheet.get_Range("F2", "F2").Font.Bold = true;

    oSheet.Cells[2, 7] = sShipToName;
    oSheet.Cells[3, 7] = sAddress;
    oSheet.Cells[4, 7] = sCityStateZip;
    oSheet.Cells[5, 7] = sContactName;
    oSheet.Cells[6, 7] = sContactPhone;

    oSheet.Cells[9, 1] = "Shipment No:";
    oSheet.get_Range("A9", "A9").Font.Bold = true;
    oSheet.Cells[9, 2] = sJobNumber;

    oSheet.Cells[9, 6] = "Courier:";
    oSheet.get_Range("F9", "F9").Font.Bold = true;
    oSheet.Cells[9, 7] = sCarrierName;

    oSheet.Cells[11, 1] = "Requested Delivery Date:";
    oSheet.get_Range("A11", "A11").Font.Bold = true;
    oSheet.Cells[11, 2] = sRequestDeliveryDate;

    oSheet.Cells[11, 6] = "Courier Acct No:";
    oSheet.get_Range("F11", "F11").Font.Bold = true;
    oSheet.Cells[11, 7] = sCarrierAcctNum;
    // *****

    Method #1
    //oWB.SaveCopyAs(@"C:\Temp\" + sJobNumber +".xls");

    Method #2
    oXL.SaveWorkspace(sJobNumber + ".xls");
}
catch (Exception theException)
{
    String errorMessage;
    errorMessage = "Error: ";
    errorMessage = String.Concat(errorMessage, theException.Message);
    errorMessage = String.Concat(errorMessage, " Line: ");
    errorMessage = String.Concat(errorMessage, theException.Source);
}
```

Comment: Kris, please read the FAQ at http://stackoverflow.com/faq. This is not how tags work.

Comment: Thank you for this valuable information.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the savefiledialog and have the user select their location, then u can use that location when u call oWB.SaveCopyAs(userselectedlocation)

Answer (score 3):

Use a SaveFileDialog class to get the desire path from the user:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.savefiledialog.aspx

Comment: Does this only works for windows forms? I am trying to get the save as dialog from a web application.

Comment: @Kris: Nowhere its mentioned in your post that its a web app; I think you should add your web app tag as well(for instance asp.net).

Comment: @KMan: Sorry, I forgot that piece. :)

Answer (score 1):

Why aren't you using `SaveFileDialog`? See [How to: Save Files Using the SaveFileDialog Component](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sfezx97z(VS.85).aspx)

**--EDIT--**

If its asp.net app, then [this discussion](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sharepointdevelopment/thread/71726d31-2759-4c2a-8507-6813316dac21) might help to produce a save file dialog.

Answer (score -2):

You can try this. I tried, and it worked for me

```
oWB.SaveAs(@"C:\Temp\" + "test" + ".xlsx");
```